# Past && YTD percentile ratings to describe your rep on a resume

Tags: feature-request, reputation, reputation-leagues, top-users

If you're a top user, how do you describe your rep on the resume?

I've noticed my SO profile has had ["top 2% this year" on 2017-06-24](http://web.archive.org/web/20170624192550/https://stackoverflow.com/users/1122270/cnst), but [2017-07-29 shows "top 2% this week"](http://archive.is/NRH7o), which may be a better short-term accomplishment, but is not really something that'd be meaningful in print.  (Frankly, I'm honestly not even sure if I've slipped to top-3%-this-year spot, or whether SO just thinks that letting me know that I'm top-2%-this-week is a better and newer rank.)

***Is there a way to get a resume-ready percentile ratings for YTD, as well as the prior years?***  Would probably be useful to have these for the past 4 full quarters, and 12 full months as well.

Comment: [At what point do you put your SO reputation in your resume?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58947/at-what-point-do-you-put-your-so-reputation-in-your-resume?rq=1)

Comment: @Dukeling https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149363/221016

Comment: "Top 2%" is rounded, but (for whatever reason) the display uses the highest *unrounded* percentile. So you might be in the top 2.01529% of this year, but the top 2.00387% of this week, and it will show the week instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could go back to the relevant time periods and do some short math.

Let's say I wanted to know my percentage for last quarter. There should be a `prev quarter` button in a blue box like this one (remember, we're in the third not second quarter):

[image]

You can go back all the way to the first league ever in Meta Stack Exchange. Of course, you can change what site leagues you want to see. Okay, back to me. I can calculate my percentage within *the league* with some simple math:

```
          my rank
-----------------------------  =  MY PERCENTAGE!
number of people in my league
```

My rank was 63 last quarter. You can simply find the number of people by looking at the last person's rank in the last page for that league. The person in last is at rank 531 so the math would be:

```
 63
------ = 0.118644068
 531
```

Multiply that by 100 to get the percentage for 11 percent. Wanna check why that's true? Let's do the same thing for me currently, this time it will be the year. If you check my profile, it says `top 0.43% this year`.

My rank is 15, there is 3510 people in the leagues last year and the math says:

```
  15
------ = 0.0042735... which is about 0.0043
 3510
```

Multiply that by 100 and you get 0.43%!

Comment: That seems too unofficial, cumbersome and lacking adequate proofs.

Comment: @cnst There's no official way (at least that I know of) but how is there no adequate proof?

Comment: I just think it'd be in bad style to manually calculate your rating, especially if it would conflict with the info presented on the official site, meaning, no clear proof that your calculation is actually correct.  The whole idea of rating is that they're independent; if SO makes a mistake in their calculation, it's their problem — I did my due diligence, so did the recruiter.  I don't want to worry about making a mistake, especially given that the system is closed source, and poorly documented (sorry — but it's true!), so, it's not too hard to imagine that we'd misinterpret the data.

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow has a built-in resume they make on their own, it's known as Developer Story.

In there, there is already live display of your rank *per tag*, which is better and more useful than the overall reputation which doesn't mean too  much anyway.

For example, taken from [my Developer Story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/447356):

> [image]

Other than that, we don't really have other "resume-ready percentile ratings" that I know of.

Comment: It depends on your niche, and the rank per tag may not work for everyone.  I'd imagine that it won't work for someone's who's just recently joined, too, for example; as well as for generalists that don't really specialise in any one particular thing.  Also, the rank per tag may be highly misleading — I'm top-10% for PHP.  I met the guy who wrote it, but don't know any PHP at all; I use Go, C and tcsh, for all of which I don't even have any ranking at all on careers.  And, sure, being top-1% for nginx is nice for me, but I think that would be too specific and too niche for a recruiter.

Comment: *"more useful than the overall reputation which doesn't mean too much anyway"* — I believe that's an observer bias; I'm top-1% nginx (and probably still top-2% overall), which is all helpful; but i'm also top-10% PHP, which I don't claim any knowledge of at all.  Even Yelp has yearly-based awards for its most active active users.  You can argue that you guys have badges, but all of those don't really mean anything even to most folks who are actual active users at SO, let alone any outsider.  A yearly-based top rating is clearly warranted. You wouldn't even need to update it any often, if ever.

Comment: plus, it would seem that Careers top completely disregards ServerFault — there's more to it than just the name and site rep as a number