# Previous year(s) ranking on a site (Stack Overflow)

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-leagues, user-rank

Is there a way to get your previous year (2020) ranking on Stack Overflow and/or other sites.

1. The all-time rank becomes a bit irrelevant for someone who has not been active before last year.
2. The current year ranking is great, but it's again somewhat irrelevant for the first quarter in the current year.

I couldn't find anything of this sort in my Google searches!

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2020-01-01/4755954?sort=reputationchange#4755954

Comment: didnt imagine it would be this easy. thanks a ton! if you could post it as an answer i could accept!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On [the year reputation league page](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/), there is a <kbd>« prev year</kbd> link under **Year 2021** to get rankings for Year 2020.

> [image: previous year button]

Your rank for 2020 can be found [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2020-01-01/4755954?sort=reputationchange#4755954).

Comment: A quick question. Is there a straightforward way to calculate `top x%` from the `#rank`?

Comment: @AkshaySehgal Calculating `top %` is described in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299036/388442).